# Stroustrup 4th edition, page 82, variadic template example does not compile

Tags: c++, variadic

The following is the gist of the code, which fails to compile on g++ 4.7.1

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> void bottom(T x) {cout << x << " ";}

template <typename Head, typename Tail...> 
void recurse(Head h, Tail t) {bottom(h); recurse(t...)}

void recurse(){}

int main() { recurse(1,2.2); }
```

For reasons unknown, the "void recurse(){}" is not participating in the template recursion.

Looking for a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few syntactic problems with that code (I doubt that you copy-pasted *as is* from Bjarne's book), but after fixing them, it seems the main problem is that the overload of `recurse()` accepting no arguments appears only after the function template `recurse()`.

Moving it before it fixes the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void bottom(T x) {cout << x << " ";}

void recurse(){} // <== MOVE THIS BEFORE THE POINT WHERE IT IS CALLED

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
void recurse(Head h, Tail... t)
{
    bottom(h);
    recurse(t...);
}

int main() { recurse(1,2.2,4); }
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/m22Kku).

Comment: Ahh thanks. In 4th Ed pg 82 it in fact appears after. Sorry about the typos, currently struggling with cut & paste between virtual and host.

Comment: Reported erratum to Stroustrup, reply was "Thanks"

Comment: @phunctor: Well done, perhaps he didn't have a lot of time ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of typos.

1. Following code is incorrect

   ```
   template <typename Head, typename Tail...>
   ```

   It should be

   ```
   template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
   ```
2. Parameter pack should be expanded with `...`

   ```
   void recurse(Head h, Tail... t)
   ```
3. Missed `;`, `(` and `...`(again)

   ```
   bottom(h); recurse(t...);
   ```
4. `void recurse() {}` should be declared before template function to allow call `recurse` with no arguments.

The following code works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void bottom(T x)
{
    cout << x << " ";
}

void recurse()
{

}

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
void recurse(Head h, Tail... t)
{
    bottom(h);
    recurse(t...);
}

int main()
{
    recurse(1,2.2);
}
```